# ffmpeg av1-converted files don't play

Tags: ffmpeg

If i download an av1 file, then vlc player will play it perfectly

however, if i convert an mp4 (avc video, aac audio) to av1, then vlc player won't play it

this is the command i'm using with ffmpeg:

```
C:\Users\l\Desktop\6-app\ffmpeg -i y.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -strict 
experimental -vf scale=640:360 -r 30 -ab 192k -ar 48k -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 z.mkv
```

? why won't vlc player play this

I can't post the ffprobes here because of charachter limits

however, i have the ffprobe results here

[ffprobe.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awa5x8ez5s4h0wo/ffprobe.txt)

here's the file that was used to convert to av1

[club-1-head-roll-vert-half.mp4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wze3ley4s7bi956/club-1-head-roll-vert-half.mp4)

here's the non-working file

[club-test-2.mkv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncq9oihvgggnh4r/club-test-2.mkv)

Comment: Share full log of ffprobe for both files.

Comment: @gyan https://www.dropbox.com/s/awa5x8ez5s4h0wo/ffprobe.txt

Comment: I can play file generated using your command in VLC 4.0 nightly and Potplayer.

Comment: @gyan neither video player worked for me (inluding potplayer beta) · here's the non-working video file https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncq9oihvgggnh4r/club-test-2.mkv

Comment: Can you provide the source y.mp4?

Comment: @gyan https://www.dropbox.com/s/wze3ley4s7bi956/club-1-head-roll-vert-half.mp4

Comment: Works here. Upgrade ffmpeg to latest git.

Comment: @gyan · that solved it, thanks

Comment: @Gyan - maybe post that as an answer. It's hidden in the comments and if people come here looking for the answer to this question they may not see it.

Comment: @stib - it likely has to do with a transient bug in bitstream coding with the AV1 encoder. Since the encoder is still marked as experimental, these sort of issues are expected, and may recur with newer versions, so the 'answer' can't be used as a solution.